# Loading specific json message_ids according to the selected indexPath

Tags: swift, watchkit

**Goal:**
When I select a message from the list of chat messages in the `MessageListController` with `didSelectRowAt`, I want the opened chat session in the next `ChatDetailController` to match the same conversation that was selected. Obviously.

I'm working with WatchKit but it's the same thing in this iOS image. The message with Sophia is selected and the chat with Sophia opens. 
[image]

I want to pass the json "message_id" i.e. the `chatMessageId` property from my model. I'm already passing the `chatMessageId` from the `MessageModel`to the `ChatDetailController` with this line `presentController(withName: "ChatDetailController", context: messageContext)`

Here is a print out of the passed data using `messageContext`.

> Passed context: Optional(HTWatch_Extension.MessageModel(partner: "9859", nickname: "Marco", message: "Have you seen is dog?", city: "Madrid", countryBadgeImageURL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3ZO.jpg, messageListImageURL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3ZO.jpg, chatMessageId: "Tva9d2OJyWHRC1AqEfKjclRwXnlRDQ", status: "offline"))

What's the next step? **How do I tell the `ChatDetailController` to populate its table with the conversation that matches the row that was selected?**

MessageListController

```
// ...code...

let messageObject = [MessageModel]()
//var chatObject = [ChatModel]()

// ...code...

override func table(_ table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAt rowIndex: Int) {

    var messageContext = messageObject[rowIndex]
    var chatContext = chatObject[rowIndex]

    do {
        guard let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Chats", withExtension: "json") else {
            print("File could not be located")
            return
        }
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        let msg = try decoder.decode([ChatModel].self, from: data)
        self.chatObject = msg

    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }

    // I got part of this line from a previous question, but these property types do not match.
    // No matter what chatObject I create I cannot access it/assign it. 
    // Also I do not want to mutate messageContext which Xcode is telling me to do.
    messageContext.chatMessageId = (chatObject as AnyObject).filter { (dictionaryTemp:[String:String]) -> Bool in
        return dictionaryTemp["message_id"] == chatContext.chatMessageId
    } 

    // WatchKit's model presentation method.
    presentController(withName: "ChatDetailController", context: messageContext)
}
```

ChatDetailController

```
var chats: [ChatModel] = []

    var messageModel: MessageModel? {
        didSet {
            guard let model = messageModel else { return }             
            partnerLabel.setText(model.nickname)             
        }
    }

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        if let message = context as? MessageModel {

            self.messageModel = message
            print("Passed context: \(String(describing: messageModel))")
        } else {
            print("Passed context error: \(String(describing: context))")
        }

        do {
            guard let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Chats", withExtension: "json") else {
                print("File could not be located")
                return
            }
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()

            let msg = try decoder.decode([ChatModel].self, from: data)
            self.chats = msg

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            self.setupTable(chatMessageArray: self.chats as [AnyObject])
        })      
    }
```

ChatModel

```
public struct ChatModel: Codable {
// ... other properties
public var chatMessageId: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    // ... other cases
    case chatMessageId = "message_id"
}

init (message:String , fromId:String, toID : String, imgUrl : URL?, chatMessageId : String) {
    // ... other properties
    self.chatMessageId = chatMessageId
   }    
  }
 // .... decoders etc
}
```

MessageModel

```
public struct MessageModel: Codable {
    // ...
    public var chatMessageId: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    // ... other cases
    case chatMessageId = "message_id"
}
// ... init/decoders etc
}
```

Messages.json

```
[
  {
    "userid": "4444",
    "nickname": "Marco",
    "online_status": "offline",
    "message": "Have you seen his dog?",
    "city": "Madrid",
    "flag_url": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3ZO.jpg",
    "creationDate": "2016-02-22 15:18:40",
    "avatar_url": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3ZO.jpg",
    "message_id": "Tva9d2OJyWHRC1AqEfKjclRwXnlRDQ" // different id
  },
  {
      "userid": "12121",
      "nickname": "Tom",
      "online_status": "online",
      "message": "Where is the pizza shop?",
      "city": "Kyoto",
      "flag_url": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3ZO.jpg",
      "creationDate": "2016-02-22 15:18:40",
      "avatar_url": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3ZO.jpg",
      "message_id": "EnotMkk8REEd0DHGvUgnd45wBap80E" // different id
  }
]
```

Chats.json

2 conversations containing 2 messages each. Each conversation has a unique `fromId` (partner), `toID` (myself), and unique `message_id`.

```
[
  {
    "fromId": "zz1234skjksmsjdfwe2zz",
    "toId": "qq43922sdkfjsfmmxdfqq",
    "messageText": "Have you seen is dog?",
    "imageUrl": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3ZO.jpg",
    "message_id": "Tva9d2OJyWHRC1AqEfKjclRwXnlRDQ", // conversation 1  - same message id as the 1st message in Messages.josn with nickname Marco.
    "read": "true"                                      
  },
  {
      "fromId": "zz1234skjksmsjdfwe2zz",
      "toId": "qq43922sdkfjsfmmxdfqq",
      "messageText": "Yes I have. It's cute.",
      "imageUrl": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3ZO.jpg",
      "message_id": "Tva9d2OJyWHRC1AqEfKjclRwXnlRDQ", // conversation 1
      "read": "true"
  },
  {
      "fromId": "bb888skjaaasjdfwe2333",
      "toId": "qq43922sdkfjsfmmxdfqq",
      "messageText": "What kind of pizza do you want?",
      "imageUrl": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3ZO.jpg",
      "message_id": "EnotMkk8REEd0DHGvUgnd45wBap80E", // conversation 2 - same message id as the 2nd message in Messages.josn with nickname Tom.
      "read": "true"
  },
  {
      "fromId": "bb888skjaaasjdfwe2333",
      "toId": "qq43922sdkfjsfmmxdfqq",
      "messageText": "I like ham & pineapple pizza.",
      "imageUrl": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3ZO.jpg",
      "message_id": "EnotMkk8REEd0DHGvUgnd45wBap80E", // conversation 2
      "read": "true"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```swift
let msg = try decoder.decode([ChatModel].self, from: data)
self.chats = msg
```

You are storing all chat data contained in `Chats.json` into `chats` property.

To filter chats, try replacing second line like below

```swift
self.chats = msg.filter { chat in
    return chat.chatMessageId == self.messageModel.chatMessageId
}
```

or, while I don't know why all chats are contained in single json file, it will be better to separate json file into multiple files for each chat like `Chat-Tva9d2OJyWHRC1AqEfKjclRwXnlRDQ.json`.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks. If I put each chat conversation into a separate json file how do I access different the json files? Isn't it just easier to have all conversations in one file? Right now the code is `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Chats", withExtension: "json")`.

Comment: Sorry I was late marking the answer correct. I have been very busy.

Answer (score 1):

Your MessageListController `didSelectRowAt` method should be as simple as this.

```
 //MessageListController

    // ...code...

    let messageObject = [MessageModel]()
//    var chatObject = [ChatModel]()

    // ...code...

    override func table(_ table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAt rowIndex: Int) {

        //creating a context with the message object at selected row. 
        var messageContext = messageObject[rowIndex]
        // WatchKit's model presentation method. passing the context along.
        presentController(withName: "ChatDetailController", context: messageContext)

//        Rest of the codes not required in your MessageListController
    }

    // ...code...
```

Your MessageListController will be like this.

```
// ChatDetailController
    var chats: [ChatModel] = []

    var messageModel: MessageModel? {
        didSet {
            guard let model = messageModel else { return }
            partnerLabel.setText(model.nickname)
        }
    }

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        if let message = context as? MessageModel {

            self.messageModel = message
            print("Passed context: \(String(describing: messageModel))")
        } else {
            print("Passed context error: \(String(describing: context))")
        }

        do {
            guard let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Chats", withExtension: "json") else {
                print("File could not be located")
                return
            }
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()

            //msg holds all chat messages in the file
            let msg = try decoder.decode([ChatModel].self, from: data)
            // We should filter the chats in the msg array with the selected message content
            self.chats = msg.filter({
                $0.chatMessageId == messageModel?.chatMessageId
            })

//            self.chats only holds the chats with chatMessageId

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            self.setupTable(chatMessageArray: self.chats as [AnyObject])
        })
```

Hope this will resolve your issue. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Do you recommend putting all the conversations in one json file or each conversation in separate json files like pompopo suggested? If they are in separate json files how do you call the `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Chats", withExtension: "json")` line?

Comment: It is hard to maintaining multiple files for conversation. We have to determine the correct file each time when we are writing a conversation (receiving a new conversation). And same way we have to identify the files during fetching the conversation.  let fileName = “Chats-” + messageModel.chatMessageId. Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: “json”). You have to store each message conversations with name suggested by @pompopo

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I upvoted it. I appreciate your full code. It's the same answer as pompopo's, but he was first so I marked his answer as correct.